# converting class setState to functional component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Trying to learn react by coding, first i have example code which i converted to hooks then i have another one which i dont know how to convert.
My question is if the code was like this:

```
this.setState({name: 'James', destination: 'Paris'});
```

in hooks it would be like :

```
setName('James') setDestination('Paris')
```

how would i convert this to hooks (without ':')

```
this.setState({name, destination, cameras,time});
```

is it like this

```
setName(name) setDestination(destination)...
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You can create different states for each 'name' and 'destination'. Then you can use the setState separately as follows

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [destination, setDestination] = useState('');
const [cameras, setCameras] = useState('');
const [time, setTime] = useState('');
        
setName('James');
setDestination('Paris');
setCameras('');
setTime('');
```

*Modified with four states according to the comments

Another way is to create an object

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    name: "",
    destination: "",
    cameras: "",
    time: ""
});

setState({
    ...state, 
    name:"James", 
    destination:"Paris"
});
```

Comment: forget about james and paris, just need to convert this to hooks: this.setState({name, destination, cameras,time});

Comment: you can do it by splitting it into four states or you can create a state as an array

Comment: why your setting setCameras('');
if you set it like that shoudnt it be in class like this : this.setState({name, destination, cameras:'' ,time}) ?

Comment: you can set a value to cameras, I just added an empty string to show it. if you want to use the object notation you have to use colons (:)

Comment: for this you can use either of the two methods I have shown in the answer. You can create 4 states for the 4 variables and use them separately. Or you can create an Object consisting of all the 4 variables and use them together as shown in the second example

Comment: could you possibly use this code and give corrected version ?

Comment: yes, but the complete code is too long for a comment, I'll send the state block only

Comment: const [state, setState] = useState({
        name: '',
        destination: '',
        cameras: '',
        reset_time: ''
    })   
    setState({
        ...state,
        name: 'James',
        destination: 'Paris',
        cameras: 'camera 1',
        reset_time: 'time 2'
    })